# D3 Performance with large data ( & feedback needed)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bigdata

I am using d3 to make some graphs but the constraint is the number of data. To be more specific, I have an average number of points of 500,000 on a graph. 
It could go from 100,000 to 1,000,000 points on the graph.

Whenever there are 'zoom' possibilities or some other trick (that I would be pleased if someone would explain to me), I wonder if d3 (or any other lib) will really handle a 500,000 points graph.

Morever, I suppose it will depend on the client's computer, which mean they could have the latest i7 proc or a old intel pentium. For this last case, how would the browser react? I suppose it's going so slow that it will just crash?

Well, if people can give some feedback/advice please?
(Currently trying to display the data differently but my brain just imploded.)

Comment: look for down-sampling solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971519/reduce-the-size-of-a-large-data-set-by-sampling-interpolation-to-improve-chart-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have numbers or trials but I can say that I have seen `d3` go slow after certain data sizes **especially for certain types of graphs**. 500.000 seems to be quite huge in terms of data points so if you have no way to reduce that number by aggregation (such as representing 10 day data as 1 day) you might be right about worrying.

As in all performance related questions, the best way to know is to test it, so I can advice you to test it and see if it fits your requirements. If it does not you might want to try some of the non-free libraries such as `HighCharts`. Another free library which satisfies me with its performance is `Chart.js` (although it only has 6 charts supported).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using d3 for representing a massive amounts of data is the right choice due to performance:

- Vector graphics javascript library like d3 are quite heavy(for the
  client) to run.
- Complex visualization logic can easily hang the browser for multiple
  seconds.
- Large data manipulation using DOM could be slow.

Try something like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) or [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) that maybe could be more suitable for your requests.